# Random Number Generation in scripting language without using modulus or bit operations

Tags: scripting

I need to create a random number generating function in a scripting language that has no rng function, modulus, floor or bit operations.  All I have to work with are loops (for and while), if statements and [these math functions](http://gmat.ed-pages.com/wiki/tiki-index.php?page=MathOperators).  I'm completely stumped!  Any help would be great!

Comment: "I'm completely stumped!" too.  What part of this don't you understand?  Do you have an LCM algorithm?  Is that what you need?  Are you having trouble figuring out the math for the LCM algorithm?  Please be **very** specific on what problem you can't solve.

Answer (score 0):

you could seed your loops, and the order of a list of operations with the current microtime. that gives you a pseudo-random seed number and building from there, you can set rules for changing the order of operations and number of operations to take place for that loop and whether some metric has been met to break from the loop. I'd get clarification if using current microtime is allowed.